# Too many redirects?

Tags: .htaccess

I've used the '[Redirect mapper](https://varvy.com/tools/redirects/)' tool by Varvy.com, and it's highlighted an issue with my `www` redirect. I'd like there to be only one redirect, but the tool shows two redirects. See screenshot below.

This is what I'm using in my `htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

As the screenshot shows, http://www.d3creative.uk 302 redirects to http**s**://www.d3creative.uk/, then 301 redirects to https://d3creative.uk/

I'd like to http://www.d3creative.uk/ to 301 redirect to https://d3creative.uk/, skipping the www redirect.

[image: Screenshot of Redirect mapper tool]

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**

I use [ServerPilot](https://serverpilot.io/) to manage my server, and I've setup SSL using ServerPilot.

I've removed the original `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` lines from my `htaccess` file

This clears up the multiple redirects (see screenshot below), but I still need a way to redirect `www` to `non-www`

I've contacted ServerPilot support, I'll post back here with any answers.

[image]

Comment: The 302 redirection is _not_ caused by those rules you posted. There has to be something else in your configuration. Probably not in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"), but in the real http servers host configuration which is the preferred location for such rules anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

Within the ServerPilot control panel there is an option to force a HTTPS redirect. This was conflicting with any redirects I was using in my `htaccess` file.

Turn 'Redirect to HTTPS' off and use the ruleset below in your `htaccess`

ServerPilot support kindly provided this ruleset, which works great.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

All versions of my domain now redirect (once) to my preferred version of the domain.

[image: Screenshot]